# Send Woocommerce buying order to a particular URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to make Woocommerce communicate the buying order to a particular URL when you buy something. I have an RP on that URL with a program that does some math with the data to display different things to the user.

I have been trying to find the answer to my question on how to achieve this for a few days but I can´t seem to find it. I don't know if there is a really simple way or if, on the contrary, this takes a lot of work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean that you would like to display the order in a particular URL? Then if it's that, how do you communicate this Url and who can view it (view restrictions)…

Comment: Try adding external product. So it will get you to another URL while purchasing :)

Comment: It is not really that I want to display another URL once the buy is successful. What I want is the order to be communicated to an external URL where I can have an API running some math to display in the user profile their purchased item.  The user doesn't have to be sent to the URL, just a call in the back-end. @Mujeebu Rahman

Comment: @HéctordePradaGonzález Have you had a chance to find an answer for this? I am looking something similar and unfortunately stuck..